# Splitting value from one row to other rows in the same column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question regarding to pandas

I have got a DataFrame df

| TaskId | UserId | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123456 | 19 |
| 123456 | 123456 | NaN |
| 123456 | 123456 | NaN |
| 123456 | 123456 | NaN |
| 654321 | 654321 | 10 |

Now I want to split the 19 from the first row into equal amounts where the TaskId and UserId is the same
19 / 4 = 4.75

This is what I would like to receive

| TaskId | UserId | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 123456 | 4.75 |
| 123456 | 123456 | 4.75 |
| 123456 | 123456 | 4.75 |
| 123456 | 123456 | 4.75 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I couldn't find anything here on stackoverflow

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for divide first values by counts:

```
g = df.groupby(['TaskId','UserId'])['Hours']
df['Hours'] = g.transform('first').div(g.transform('size'))
print (df)

   TaskId  UserId  Hours
0  123456  123456   4.75
1  123456  123456   4.75
2  123456  123456   4.75
3  123456  123456   4.75
4  654321  654321  10.00
```